# What does "truncated gradients" mean in LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm learning a tensorflow tutorial about LSTM: [Truncated Backpropagation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#truncated-backpropagation).

This section says the code uses "truncated backpropagation", so what exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a neural network setting in general (well, most of the time) you perform two steps during training:

FORWARD PASS

- Show some inputs to the net, and check the output
- Compute a loss on the output (versus labels, or versus some behavior you want)

BACKWARD PASS

- With the computed loss and the state of your net you calculate gradients to be applied to the weights of your net in order for it to learn.
- These gradients are applied from your output layer backwards.

In the backward pass it might be that, for some reason, you only want to train the top layer or only some specific parts of your net. In this case you would want to stop the backwards passing of gradients at that point. This is what truncating backpropagation does (often done via [https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#stop_gradient)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#stop_gradient).

Comment: Does this have the same effect as setting some of the layers untrainable (freeze the weights and biases)?

Comment: Yes, in a sense. 

You can make layers untrainable, but if prior (lower) layer still are trainable, gradients will flow the freezed layers (without modifying weights there) and train those lower layers. Stopping a gradient really stops them there. The lower layers might still remain trainable through gradients coming through other routes.

One is gradient specific, the other layer specific. But yes, they do very similar things.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @friesel's answer, I'd say that the truncated back-propagation is applied not only for speeding-up the procedure of gradient calculation but also easing some potential problems in recurrent neural network(e.g. vanishing gradient & gradient explosion).

Comment: I thought LSTM does not suffer from vanishing/exploding gradient problem, so no need to truncate back-propagation? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Truncated back-propagation aims at speeding up learning sequences (e.g. with LSTM), by computing approximate gradients on "short" sequences, instead of on full sequences. I guess this is what the documentation means by making "the learning process tractable".

This method seems to originate from the work of Mikolov on "Statistical Language Models based on Neural Networks" (his thesis). And as explained by Alex Graves in a [well-cited paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850) (page 9):

> This form of truncated back propagation has been considered before for RNN language modelling [23], and found to speed up training (by reducing the sequence length and hence increasing the frequency of stochastic weight updates) without affecting the network’s ability to learn long-range dependencies.

[23] is Mikolov's thesis.

---

In short, truncated back-propagation is a "trick" to speed up learning over sequences, without losing (too much) significant information. Note that truncating too much can backdraft (i.e. lose significant information).

Answer (score 0):

For others stumbling across this post, 'truncated gradient' can also refer to an online version of LASSO-type regularization. See for example [Stochastic Gradient Descent Training forL1-regularized Log-linear Models with Cumulative Penalty (2009)](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P09-1054.pdf).